# Yet another password validating regular expression

Tags: regex

I've gone through multiple examples to validate passwords via regular expression, but none of them quite fit what I am looking for. I've been using trial and error to build my own, but without complete success.

Here is the regular expression that so far is the closest match for what I am looking for:

```
(?=.*?[a-z]{3,})(?=.*?[A-Z]{3,})(?=.*?[0-9]{2,})[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,24}
```

The password should have three lowercase and three uppercase alphabets and two numbers. Password length should be between 8 and 24 characters. Special characters are not looked for, they can be used as long as other requirements are met.

The regular expression above matches `ABCdef12` but does not match `Ad1Be1Cf`. How I should modify the regular expression so it also matches the latter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use look aheads for the content assertion, and a simple regex for the length:

```
^(?=(.*[a-z]){3})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*\d){2}).{8,24}$
```

See [demo](http://rubular.com/r/GKMeQEWiRi)

I'm reasonably confident this this the shortest regex that will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
  (?=.{8,24}$)(?=.*?[a-z].*?[a-z].*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z].*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d.*?\d)(^.*$)
```

You can use this.It uses lookahead to test all conditions.

See Demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yX3eB5/9